# what is the basic idea for making bioplastic?

Tags: plastics, green-chemistry

I have the following questions about making bioplastics:

1. Why is only lactic acid used in making bioplastic?
2. Are there any other methods used in making bioplastic without converting
   starch into lactic acid?
3. What are the features of lactic acid that makes it suitable for
   making bioplastic?
4. Are there any alternatives for making good bioplastic?

Comment: This question as it stands is too broad please ask the 4 questions separately

Answer (score 3):

A general answer to your broad question is that poly(lactic acid) is used because fermentation of sugar to lactic acid is easy and has high mass yield, and polymerization to the polyester is straightforward. But it's not the only bioplastic. There are many others in use or in development. For example, ethanol from fermentation can be dehydrated to ethylene which is polymerized to polyethylene.

So yes, there are other methods and other alternatives to PLA. If you are interested in a particular application, I would recommend researching possible materials for that application and asking a more specific question about the comparable qualities of materials for that application.